# Maximum execution time for exporting a MYSQL database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export a giant database on my local hosting using cpanel.  I get this error even though I've set the php.ini max execution time to a huge number: max_execution_time=9999. Any thoughts?

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp2\phpMyAdmin\libraries\session.inc.php on line 108
```

Comment: Did you restart Apache after making the change in php.ini?

Comment: You really should be using `mysqldump`, or for really large databases, [`innobackupex`](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/innobackupex_script.html)

Comment: May I suggest you contact your hosting provider's support and request help? They may be able to get you a backup file that you can download. Hosting providers use an override on `max_execution_time` to keep their costs down, etc.